# Cant loop itemrenderer, how to put value in i?

Tags: xml, apache-flex

```
<s:ItemRenderer>

    <s:Label text="{selectedSpeler.AwayScore[i]}"/> 

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

I have 16 AwayScore return from my api call giving me xml, every AwayScore gives me xml namespaces if i dont use [0]. how do i let my label print out 16 times?

Answer (score 0):

ItemRenderers are used with list based classes, such a List or DataGrid.  Set the dataProvider of a List based class to `selectedSpeler.AwayScore`.  Then inside your itemRenderer, use the data property to access the individual elements of your XML.

Conceptually something like this:

```
<s:List dataProvider = "{selectedSpeler.AwayScore}">
<s:ItemRenderer>
    <s:Label text="{data.somePropertyOnYourXML}"/> 
</s:ItemRenderer>
</s:List>
```

For best results; you'll want to turn your XML variable into an XMLListCollection.  Without knowing anything about your data structure, or how you load it, I am unable to provide more specific details.

Comment: <ArrayOfScore xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Score>
<AwayScore>20</AwayScore>
<AwayScoreOvertime>0</AwayScoreOvertime>
<AwayScoreQuarter1>0</AwayScoreQuarter1>
<AwayScoreQuarter2>7</AwayScoreQuarter2>
<AwayScoreQuarter3>10</AwayScoreQuarter3>
<AwayScoreQuarter4>3</AwayScoreQuarter4>
<YardLineTerritory i:nil="true"/>
</Score><Score></Score> this is 16 times

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to communicate with your comment.

Comment: @user3060452 `Score` does not represent an Array; it represents an Object with properties (`AwayScore`, `AwayScoreOverTime`, etc.). As Reboog711 already mentioned, you can only use ILists as dataProvider for list based components. All the items in there should be of the same type. For example: `<Score type="Away" value="20"/><Score type="AwayOvertime" value="0"/>` etc.